# Alignment after array member of same type

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, struct, alignment

In the common situation of a struct/class there may be alignment padding between members.  But I am wondering whether it would be safe to assume that this special case:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct MyStruct {
    T data[N];
    T term;
    constexpr MyStruct();
};
```

would be reliably the equivalent of this:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
struct MyStruct {
    T data[N+1];
    constexpr MyStruct();
};
```

The reason for asking is that what I actually want is to be able to explicitly initialise the last member of the array in a constexpr constructor (but I don't care about the rest).  For example with the top MyStruct I can do this:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
constexpr MyStruct<T,N>::MyStruct() : data{}, term{0} {}
```

But I want the result to be the same as if term was really the last element of the array.

Is this safe?  If not, is there a way to achieve the same thing using the second form of MyStruct?

Comment: According to §5.3.6 the array and the type have the same alignment, so there shouldn't be any padding. But in §9.2 it says _"[..] Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions (10.3) and virtual base classes (10.1)."_ Can anyone construct a case where this fails?

Comment: Thanks, that's useful.  I've tried various experiments with gcc and not found a failure yet.  I'm playing only with simple structures, my current use-case won't need virtual types involved.

Comment: I would be tempted to use a `union` and do some `static_assert` size mathematics at the very least.  And some `assert` math to make sure that `&two.last == &one.arr[N-1]`.

Comment: @Yakk The static_assert is a very good idea.  Under gcc at least, it turns out that the union wasn't necessary (which is good, gcc has issues with unions and constexpr).  This assert inside the constructor appears to work: `static_assert(&term == &data[N], "Invalid MyStruct");`

Comment: UB isn't so bad if you can make the compiler yell about it at compilation time.

Comment: I agree.  Considering the particular requirement I have for this, I am quite content to proceed now with the static_assert in place.  I don't know why I didn't think to try it before.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not safe to *assume* no gap between your data[N] and your term variable.  For example, you can explicitly control how  Microsoft compiler aligns variables to   n-byte boundaries (where n is 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16), see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: The linked article says "When you specify this option, each structure member after the first is stored on either the size of the member type or n-byte boundaries (where n is 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16), **whichever is smaller**."  So it seems to me that the compiler could still choose to align the similar types together - indeed that statement would seem to suggest that I am safe (given that data[N] and term are of the same type as described above).

Comment: Sure, if you're free to choose /Zp1 with the Microsoft compiler then you will be OK.  But if you're writing code that might be used on many compilers then you're definitely not OK, and even with Microsoft it may turn out that /Zp1 conflicts with something else that you're doing.  My suggestion would be to try and find another way, and then you don't need to worry about this.  In my experience, these low level issues always come back and bite you eventually!

Comment: Note that the "whichever is smaller" refers to the choice between the size of the member and the alignment - so the /Zp switch shouldn't matter.  A char would still align at 1 (with no spacing because the array finished on that boundary), a word at 2, and so on.  If T turns out to be some odd sized structure over the alignment size things get more complicated to work out, though it seems to test out okay.  But I do take your point about low level issues coming back to bite.